# Turn differential upside down?

Tags: partial-derivative

I saw some theoretical physics exercise and found a statement like
$\frac{\partial V}{\partial p}=f$. In the next step the author concluded $\frac{\partial p}{\partial V}=\frac{1}f$.

This conclusion looks terribly wrong to me, but seems to work in the given example.

Now I wonder: Are there any mathematical conditions that would allow such a conclusion?

Comment: We need to be able to write $p(V)$, of course, which requires that $V$ be invertible at the point $p$ in question, i.e. $p(V(p)) = p$ (forgive my abuse of notation). Then, it follows neatly from the derivative rule for inverse functions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Reciprocal" of derivatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185004/reciprocal-of-derivatives)